# How to Scroll a Cell to visible location automatically when i tap the cell

Tags: xcode4.2

I have the table view, that contain a customized tableview cell. The cell contain UILabel and UIView.Initially UIview is hidden.After tapping that cell only i make it visible.In order to make the auto scrolling i use ScrollRecttoVisible function. But it is not working for last few cell.Could anybody help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I personally use `– scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` to scroll to the cell at the given position, with `UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle` for the atScrollPosition argument.